# Worms 2 on Windows 10 "frontend.exe has stopped working"

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, worms-2

This is all I get.

When I try to edit a map, start a game, start a quick game, etc, I get this.

[image: Worms 2 crash on Win10]

It doesn't immediately crash or anything, I can go through the menus, but if I do anything that would require starting a external application that isn't `frontend.exe`, it crashes.

Comment: Have you tried running the game it in compatibility mode? If that doesn't work, try locating *all* `.exe`s used by the game and set all of them to compatibility mode.

Comment: @MrLemon I've tried, but i've absolutely **NEVER** fixed a compatibility problem in my **ENTIRE** life using compatibility mode.